# Is there an elegant, Pythonic way to count processed data?

Tags: python, loops, counter

I often have time consuming processing steps that occur within a loop.  The following method is how I keep track of where the processing is at.  Is there a more elegant, Pythonic way of counting processing data while a script is running?

---

```
n_items = [x for x in range(0,100)]

counter = 1
for r in n_items:
    # Perform some time consuming task...
    print "%s of %s items have been processed" % (counter, len(n_items))
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the counter approach.

Comment: `counter += 1` maybe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) was built for this:

```
for i,r in enumerate(n_items,1):
    # Perform some time consuming task
    print('{} of {} items have been processed'.format(i, len(n_items)))
```

The second argument determines the starting value of `i`, which is `0` by default.

Comment: Pass 1 as second argument.

Comment: This is a nice alternative.  The syntax should be the following: `print '{} of {} items have been processed'.format(i, len(n_items))`

Comment: The `print` syntax I gave is mandatory in Python 3, and should also be valid in Python 2.